# How can I implement thread in Android MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy, synchronized

I am recently working with Android,I have MainActivity class .
I am using Android Studio and my problem is that
I want to connect to a bluetooth device by connect method, but it takes time and I want this method to be done and then the next line to be executed. Unfortunately synchronized and thraed do not work, moreover i have generate a sample in Intellij idea and it has worked.I should say ,i am using callback in connect method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private GenericBleService genericBleService;
    private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    @Override
    protected  synchronized void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("D9:69:99:AA:67:47");

        genericBleService = new GenericBleService().getInstance(bluetoothDevice, getApplication());

        /////////////// this is connect method \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
        genericBleService.connect(bluetoothDevice.getAddress());

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("getBatteryLevel " + genericBleService.getAttribute(GattAttribute.BATTERY_LEVEL));
        System.out.println("getBatteryLevel 2 : " + genericBleService.getAttribute(GattAttribute.BATTERY_LEVEL));

    }
```

and my connect method is  :

```
@Override
    public Boolean connect(String deviceAddr) {
        reentrantLock.lock();
        System.out.println("Generic Ble Service connect");
        if (GenericBleConfig.getBluetoothAdapter() == null || deviceAddr == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (deviceAddress != null && deviceAddr.equals(deviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = GenericBleConfig.getBluetoothAdapter().getRemoteDevice(deviceAddr);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.

        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(GenericBleConfig.getContext(), true, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        this.deviceAddress = deviceAddr;
        this.bluetoothDevice = device;
        System.out.println("Here is connect Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code unless you have issues with IDE itself, replace them with code blocks.

Comment: The BLE API is asynchronous, but synchronous. You don't have to, and should not, create a new thread. Instead implement the callbacks correctly.